# Is this variable disposed after use?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, clr, local

I just don't know that where the variable used in some method has gone after the method's execution completed, please see the code snippet below:

```
    void Foo()
    {
        List<object> conditionedObjList;
        conditionedObjList = GetConditionedObjectList
            (
            new List<object>() { /*there are many unconditioned objects here*/}
            );
    }
```

My question; is the variable `myObjList` defined in method `GetConditionedObjectList` will be disposed after `myObjList` has returned or we need to dispose it manually?

```
    private List<object> GetConditionedObjectList(List<object> originalObjList)
    {
        List<object> myObjList = new List<object>();
        /*do some selection*/
        myObjList.AddRange(new object[]{/*there are 100 conditioned objects here*/});
        return myObjList;
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. `GetConditionedObjectList` completely ignores its incoming parameter. (Perhaps that's irrelevant, but it obscures your question.)  When the call to `GetConditionedObjectList` returns, the local variable (in Foo) `conditionedObjList`will be a reference to the list `myObjList` that you created in `GetConditionedObjectList`. When Foo exits, there will no longer be a reference to the list, and it will be marked for garbage collection.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about garbage collection rather than disposing (which has a different meaning in .NET)

Comment: To Joel: imagine that T is string ,in the method 'GetConditionedObjectList' , I make some selection from the incoming parameter originalObjList , e.g. enumerate the list to check if the element in originalObjList is string that start with "foo", then add the element to myObjList. and return myObjList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# has garbage collection. Objects are created on the heap, and are only collected when the object has no more references to it.

`myObjList` just stores a *reference* to the actual object which is on the heap; when you return this reference and store it in a variable, you're guaranteeing that the garbage collector (GC) won't pick it up.

If by "disposed" you mean "destroyed" or "removed from memory", then the garbage collector does this for you; all you need to do is remove references to the object. For example, you could set `conditionedObjList` to `null` after calling the function. Then the GC would be free to pick the unreferenced object up. Note that this isn't immediate; the GC only runs periodically in order to be more efficient.

Comment: Merely storing a reference in a stack variable doesn't guarantee that it won't be collected: http://www.codeneverwritten.com/2007/12/04/where-did-my-object-go-part-1/

Comment: @Curt: Hmm, interesting. I tried out the example in the article but could not reproduce the behaviour on .NET 3.5 (both debug and release behave consistently, not collecting the object until after the method ends, though before Main ends). It's also a little unlikely to run into that behaviour by accident...

Answer (score 1):

**It is not disposed** as you are returning a reference to it.

It would have gone out of scope if it was only used in function locally in that case after function returns there are no references to it, therefore GC is free to collect it.

BTW `List<T>` doesn't implement IDisposable therefore it doesnt need to be disposed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

1. The List doesn't implement `IDisposable` - so we don't need to dispose it at all.
2. It will be marked to be garbage collected as soon as you not have any reference to it.